# htaccess server side rewrite not working

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have my htacess rewrite working, the pages are going to where they are supposed to, but the url bar changes and I dont want it to. I thought this was an INTERNAL redirect and whatever is in the URL would be displayed. It's not working that way.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/]+(/(.+))?$
RewriteRule . /%2 [L]
```

Basically, the url IS rewriting to the new URL. How do I get it to not do that?

Comment: OK, so when there is a subdir, you can't have a trailing slash and when there isn't a subdir, you can. That's the way this works. Regex is voodoo.

Comment: If turning off DirectorySlash doesn't work (or you don't want to turn off), try doing the directory detect yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If whatever the **%2** back reference is matching doesn't end with an extension, mod_dir might think that it's a directory. If it's missing a trailing slash, mod_dir will *externally* redirect the browser to the same URL but with a trailing slash. You could try turning `DirectorySlash Off` in your .htaccess file or server config.

### edit

You can try to bypass mod_dir's by doing the directory check yourself and adding the trailing slash so mod_dir won't redirect you. It would look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/]+(/(.+))$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2 -d
RewriteRule ^[^/]+(/(.+))$ /$2/ [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Per your last comment, try this instead

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/]+(/?|/(.+))$
RewriteRule . /%2 [L]
```

It should match an optional trailing slash e.g. `http://mydomain.com/somedir` or `http://mydomain.com/somedir/` and one with a directory after e.g `http://mydomain.com/somedir/dir2`